# Create new ISO for Live USB

Tags: live-usb

From my understanding, live USBs don't tend to hold updates or programs you've installed during your session. I've seen a few posts that tell you to just "put the files you want to backup into a folder, then use  to create ISO" but they never say anything about making a backup of the whole os.

I'd like to **install a software** onto my Ubuntu environment, **create an image**, and make a **new ISO to turn into a live USB again**, so every time I start a new session I could just connect to a cloud service to get my files and continue working from the USB. What are the steps to do this?